# How to connect pc to internet and directly to NAS using different interfaces

Tags: networking, routing, nas, traceroute

My goal is to connect my PC and my NAS directly using two USB to 5 Gbe adapters and both of them to a switch that has internet access via 1Gbe NICs.

So the initial setup was:

- QNAP TS-431P connected to the switch via ethernet port
- PC with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS connected to the same switch via ethernet port

Up to this point no problem, I can see the NAS and mount its samba share no problem.

Now what I did is add a USB ethernet adapter to my PC and to my NAS and connected them directly.

This the result of `ifconfig` on PC:

```
luca@luca-desktop:~$ ifconfig

eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.54  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::fde4:a653:afea:7688  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f4:4d:30:66:50:cb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 177340  bytes 24973154 (24.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 167118  bytes 26718368 (26.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xdf100000-df120000

enx000ec662652b: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.100.99  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        inet6 fe80::5910:d206:4380:e58f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0e:c6:62:65:2b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8512  bytes 2665143 (2.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1148  bytes 176865 (176.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 231260  bytes 50412790 (50.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 231260  bytes 50412790 (50.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.20.18.9  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.20.18.9
        inet6 fe80::fbf1:3985:1dec:aded  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 14077  bytes 2781542 (2.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21410  bytes 4027823 (4.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

On my NAS instead I have 192.168.1.4 as the IP address of the interface connected to the switch and 169.254.119.123 as the IP address of the USB adapter interface.

On my PC I have these routes:

```
luca@luca-desktop:~$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.22.18.1      128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eno1
10.0.0.243      10.22.18.1      255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 tun0
10.22.18.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.22.18.1      128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
156.146.41.87   192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eno1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 enx000ec662652b
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 enx000ec662652b
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eno1
```

But if I try and telnet to my NAS this is the result:

```
luca@luca-desktop:~$ telnet 169.254.119.123 445
Trying 169.254.119.123...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

And this is the result of a `traceroute` to the NAS two IPs

```
luca@luca-desktop:~$ traceroute 169.254.119.123
traceroute to 169.254.119.123 (169.254.119.123), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  luca-desktop.local (169.254.100.99)  3079.052 ms !H  3078.965 ms !H  3078.926 ms !H
luca@luca-desktop:~$ traceroute 192.168.1.4
traceroute to 192.168.1.4 (192.168.1.4), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.4 (192.168.1.4)  0.854 ms  0.790 ms  0.748 ms
```

Can anyone help me getting this to work?

Thanks,

Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using ifconfig has been deprecated a long time ago in favor of iproute2](https://ubuntu.com/blog/if-youre-still-using-ifconfig-youre-living-in-the-past). In fact, no work has been done in ifconfig for a couple of years and using it is not advisable anymore. Using PIPA adresses can be a problem as well, especially if you have Windows machines on your network. For the purposes of this answer, I'll use IP adresses on the 172.0.0.0 range.

The easiest way to setup links like the one you require would be to configure your interfaces using iproute2 like this:

`# ip addr add 172.0.0.1/24 dev your_usb_eth_interface`

And the same thing should be done on your NAS, adjusting the IP and interface name as required. Ex.:

`# ip addr add 172.0.0.2/24 dev your_usb_eth_interface`

Please note that by default iproute2 `ip addr add` will create a `/32` netmask, meaning that only a single IP can exist in that subnet. For that reason, we set a saner netmask to guarantee that the routing won't fail.

Answers on [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238132/direct-connection-w-ethernet-cable) can be useful as well.